# Right way to add "OnChange" to woocommerce select element?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

i need to add the `onchange="myFunction()"` to my select down below. However the select below is from woocommerce, and i want it to keep the `onchange="myFunction()"` when i update my theme.

What is the best way to achieve this? (should i go into woocommerce and edit the file with the select directly?)

```
<select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_color" data-show_option_none="yes">

<option value="">Color</option>
<option value="black" class="attached enabled">Black</option>
<option value="brown" class="attached enabled">Brown</option>

</select>
```

Or can i use javacript to add the `onchange="myFunction()"` to `<select id="pa_color">` so it keeps it when i update my theme?

Comment: Create a plugin, simple one, which will load a javascript file which will have your onChange listener.

Comment: How do i make an onchange listener Can u help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a plugin if you want to add some custom js functionality and keep it after updating or changing the theme, let's say you call it my-awesome-plugin.php and dump this file into /wp-content/plugins/my-awesome-plugin folder.

Plugin file can contain the following:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Awesome Plugin
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: A plugin that loads an awesome js file.
Author: John Doe
Author URI: http://example.com
version: 1.00
*/

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_awesome_plugin_load_js');

function my_awesome_plugin_load_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-awesome-js', plugins_url( '/js/my-awesome-js.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));
}
```

And in your plugin folder create a /js/ folder and add a file `my-awesome-js.js`

When you activate your plugin, it should load my-awesome-js.js file.

Inside this file you can add your listener.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  'use strict';


    $('#pa_color').change(function() {
       // here is your value and you can do whatever you want to do with it.
       var value = $(this).val();

    });

});
```